# Compare Date entities in JPA Criteria API

Tags: java, date, jpa-2.0, criteria-api

*Using JPA 2 with EclipseLink implementation.*

I'm trying to build a dynamic query which should bring me some records persisted after a given date.

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Event> criteria = builder.createQuery(Event.class);
Root<Event> root = criteria.from(Event.class);
criteria.select(root);
criteria.distinct(true);
List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();
//...
if (dateLimit != null){
    ParameterExpression<Date> param = builder.parameter(Date.class, "dateLimit");
    predicates.add(builder.lessThanOrEqualTo(root.get("dateCreated"), param));
}
```

`lessThanOrEqualTo()` and `le()` are the only two methods in the API which look like may help me in this case. This warning is thrown by the eclipse though:

```
Bound mismatch: The generic method lessThanOrEqualTo(Expression<? extends Y>, Expression<? extends Y>)
of type CriteriaBuilder is not applicable for the arguments (Path<Object>, ParameterExpression<Date>).
The inferred type Object is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter
<Y extends Comparable<? super Y>>
```

I can imagine that I'm not taking the correct approach for this problem but I can't find anywhere some tips or pointers for a possible solution.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

The problem is that with the string-based API it cannot infer the type for the result value of the `get`-Operation. This is explained for example in [Javadoc for Path](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/Path.html#get%28java.lang.String%29).

If you use

```
predicates.add(builder.lessThanOrEqualTo(root.<Date>get("dateCreated"), param));
```

instead, it will work fine, because it can figure out the return type from the type argument and will find out that it is comparable. Note, the use of a parameterised method invocation `root.<Date>get(...)` (see, e.g.,  [When is a parameterized method call useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781672/when-is-a-parameterized-method-call-useful)).

Another (in my opinion better) solution is to use the metamodel based API instead of the string-based one. A simple example about canonical metamodel is given for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7790794/some-basic-questions-on-criteria-from-jpa-2-0). If you have more time to invest, this is a good article about static metamodel: [Dynamic, typesafe queries in JPA 2.0](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-typesafejpa/)

Comment: NetBeans 8.2 still warns with criteria. I don't know why. `builder.greaterThanOrEqualsTo(root.get(Some_.date), date)` <> `builder.greaterThanOrEqualsTo(root.<Date>get(Some_.date), date)`

Comment: @Jin Kwon: Make sure to import `javax.persistence.criteria.Predicate`, not `java.util.function.Predicate`. That fixed it for me :)

Comment: Is not a bad import issue, it is a bug, a very old one.
to workaround you must declare it as a variable and use it as a parameter: 
`Path path = root.get( .....); builder.greaterThan(path, date);`

Answer (score 18):

You need to use the generated metamodel to access the attributes is a really safe way. If you use Strings to refer to your attributes, types can only be deduced from the explicit generic type used when calling the method, or by a type cast, or by the automatic type inference done by the compiler:

```
Path<Date> dateCreatedPath = root.get("dateCreated");
predicates.add(builder.lessThanOrEqualTo(dateCreatedPath, dateLimit));
```

Answer (score 3):

I was getting a similar error but with the syntax `predicates.add(cb.greaterThan(article.get(Article_.created), since));` and found this page. The cause for me, turned out to be that I had upgraded my project from Java 1.7 to 1.8, and in the process had configured Maven to compile for Java 1.8 as well. I simply had to change Maven compiles back to 1.7, while keeping the rest of the project at 1.8, to fix the error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, when I have worked with predicates. It worked great with all types except Date type. I tried all method and most simple way for me was:

```
predicates.add(builder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.get(criteria.getKey()), (Date)criteria.getValue()));
```

I added `(Date)` before `criteria.getValue()`, what help to recognize my value Object as Date type.