# JPA Criteria API - arithmetic with Calendar values

Tags: java, jpa, criteria-api

I am rewriting a huge search query, originally created in Hibernate Criteria. I am trying to use only standard JPA solutions. The problem I am facing with is, that I want to make a where clause like this:

```
select ... where (stopTime - startTime) > minimalLength
```

And this does not seems to possible with Calendar values, as I can't do arithmetic with them using Criteria API. Is there a solution for this?

**Update 1**

As it was mentioned in the answers (now it is deleted), Criteria API has the `sum`, `diff`, `prod` methods, but these have the signature of :

```
<N extends java.lang.Number> Expression<N>
    method(Expression<? extends N> x, Expression<? extends N> y)
<N extends java.lang.Number> Expression<N>
    method(N x, Expression<? extends N> y)
<N extends java.lang.Number> Expression<N>
    method(Expression<? extends N> x, N y)
```

So they are not usable for `Calendar` (or even for `Date`).

**Update 2**

I think, I am on the right track. I decided to use the `function` method of *CriteriaBuilder*, and use it to call the (unfortunately vendor specific) `datediff` SQL Server method. It looks like this:

```
builder.function("datediff", Integer.class, builder.literal("second"), startTime, stopTime)
```

This *nearly* works, the only problem is, that `datediff` does not work with *String* as the first parameter, it needs a keyword (i.e. "second" without quotes). Does anybody know a way to pass a literal to the function?

Comment: I had the same issue, and ran into the same dead end you encountered in your update 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, finally I gave up, and did it with HQL istead of Criteria API. Let's just hope that my issue will be fixed in the next iteration of Criteria API...

Comment: There is similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9449003/compare-date-entities-in-jpa-criteria-api
But with right answer.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and ran into the same dead end you encountered in your update 2.

The only way around this that I could think of, is to create a UDF that doesn't take the literal "second", and delegates to datediff.

```
 CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[datediff_seconds]
 (
    @from datetime,
    @to datetime
 )
 RETURNS int
 AS
 BEGIN

    RETURN datediff(second, @from, @to)

 END

 GO
```

It's a kludge, but works.

Comment: Yes, it works if you can use stored procedures, for me it was not an option.

Comment: It's a UDF, not a stored procedure; but I get your point - this is only an option if adding an SQL function to the schema is an option.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with simply converting to unix_timestamp, which are numbers and can be diff-ed. It is simply a shame that JPA can not give a parameter to a function.

```
cb.greaterThan(
  cb.diff(
    cb.function("unix_timestamp", Long.class, root.get(Table_.until)),
    cb.function("unix_timestamp", Long.class, root.get(Table_.from))
  )
, 3600L*longerThanHours)
```