# Illegal attempt to dereference path source null of basic type

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm using Spring Data JPA to create my own custom repository method:

```java
@Repository
public interface LoremRepository extends JpaRepository<LoremEntity, Long> {
    List<LoremEntity> findByCocIdAndMonth_Year(Long cocId, int year);
}
```

My **LoremEntity**:

```java
public class LoremEntity {

    // Other fields ...

    @Column(name = "MONTH")
    private ZonedDateTime month;

    @Column(name = "COC_ID")
    private Long cocId;
}
```

I'm getting this error:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query
> for method public abstract java.util.List
> com.banana.pikachu.LoremRepository
> .findByCocIdAndMonth_Year(java.lang.Long,int)! Illegal attempt to
> dereference path source [null.month] of basic type    at
> org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:96)
> at
> org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:103)
> at
> org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:209)
> at
> org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:78)
> at
> org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:574)
> at
> org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$mapMethodsToQuery$1(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:567)
> at
> java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
> at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133)

How to fix this issue?

Comment: That won't work as you cannot query for a property of `ZonedDateTime`, that would only work if `ZonedDateTime` would be an entity. So you would need to query in a range. Start of year and end of year instead of only the year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **`year`** function (and [other functions](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-functions)) in your JPQL (HQL) query, for example like this:

```java
@Query("select l from LoremEntity l where l.cocId = ?1 and year(l.month) = ?2")
List<LoremEntity> findByCocIdAndMonth_Year(Long cocId, int year);
```

*If you want to do it with **CriteriaQuery** see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52530845/2039546*